# Confusion react-router-dom and react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and redux, I started out my project with the react-router-dom, now I'm looking to add Redux in the mix.

Should I keep using react-router-dom or just install react-router-redux? or both?
Does the Route component work the same? I'm a bit confused as what the use of react-router-dom would be?

Do I switch all the Link components to an a element that dispatches an action to the store?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when using Redux, it's recommended to use react-router-redux, which encapsulates react-router.

Only when you initialize your app, you should pass a couple of things from react-router to Redux, which are `Router` and `browserHistory`.

In app.js:

```jsx
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

const initialState = {};
const store = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router
          history={history}
          routes={rootRoute}
        />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
};
```

You provide the Router element of react as a child of Redux's Provider element, and you also provide to the Router element the Redux wrapper for React's browserHistory.

In the rest of your project, you only need to use react-router-redux, rather than calling React directly.

react-router-dom BTW is just another layer of simplification in React 4 which encapsulates react-router, but in case your project architecture is Redux, than you need to work according to the rules of Redux and therefore only use react-router-redux in order to pass through the store in each action (except for the aforementioned initialization).

Comment: Looks like this is now deprecated in favor of https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router

Answer (score 1):

i will recommend you to use react-router-redux.
using react-router-redux you can connect your router state with your Redux Store so that you can Interact with the Router with the same API you use to interact with the rest of your app state.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-router-redux.

With react-router-redux the location state is kept in your redux store as plain object. This means you can inject location information with connect as you would any other state.